# ArcGIS Pro basemap transparency

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap, transparency-opacity

How do you adjust the map layer transparency in ArcGIS Pro?

I know you can adjust the base map, but I am wondering about the main map layer. I use the hybrid reference layer as my basemap, but when I adjust the transparency, it only adjusts the transparency of the roads and labels.

Answer (score 1):

The "Hybrid Reference Layer" is **part of a basemap**, not the entire basemap.  Your actual basemap is probably something like the "Imagery Hybrid" basemap.

Some of these basemaps include 2 layers:

- Reference (labels, roads, etc)
- Imagery (or similar)

It seems that your are only looking at the transparency of the Reference layer of the basemap, and not the Imagery layer of the basemap.

Note that the Reference layer is usually at the top of the layers list (in Contents and on the map), and the Imagery layer is usuallt at the bottom of the layers list, so they do not obviously belong together in the table of contents.

So find the imagery layer (eg, "World Imagery" for the "Imagery Hybrid" layer) and then configure the transparency for that layer:

- Click on the Imagery basemap layer to select it (in the table of contents - not the Reference basemap layer!)
- Click 'Appearance' (ribbon tab)
- Enter a value in 'Transparency' (ribbon field)